# Что лучше использовать для системы Django или FastAPI или Laravel?

Tags: php, linux, django, laravel, fastapi

Летом начал писать backend для системы, которая должна принимать запросы от клиента, сохранять их в базу данных **clickhouse**. Я начал всё писать на php8.0 при использовании фреймворка **laravel**. По началу возникло много сложностей с системой авторизации, но это дела минувшего прошлого.

Часть системы уже написана. Не скажу, что очень много сделано. Средняя скорость ответа на запрос: **300 мс**. В инете написано, что это нормально. Однако это тестирование на 1м клиенте. Так что скорее всего при множестве одновременных запросов время ответа увеличится.

Сейчас подобрался к описанию взаимодействия с **mqtt**. Нужно, чтобы сервер отправлял на **mqtt** по топику device/device_id команды, а так же их принимал. Как я подозреваю,эта система не очень будет работать на php так как мне нужно будет сделать listner'a, который будет считывать сообщения с топика. 1 дело, если это будет ответ от устройства, что оно приняло команду. Это не должно занимать много времени. А другое дело, если Я должен ожидать выполнение работы устройством. На php нет реализации нескольких потоков, лишь имитация. То есть я не смогу выделить поток, который будет спрашивать у устройства: готово ли это или нет или выделить поток, который просто будет смотреть по топику, проверяя, есть ли там новое сообщение.

Обозначив перед коллегами такой вопрос мне предложили всё переписать на Django. Я сел изучать вопрос. Прочитал про лицензию Django,написано, что бесплатно. Так же наткнулся на FastAPI, пишется, что он весьма быстр (да, это можно понять по названию).

Вычитал, что Django не обладает тоже многопоточностью, однако на нём просто будет удобнее и легче написать многие функции из моего php кода, плюс высокая степень безопасности.
По поводу FastAPI вычитал, что у него нет встроенного хорошего модуля безопасности, зато есть многопоточность и автодокументирование.

И вот у меня встал выбор. Продолжать реализовывать на php, начать переписывать на Django или FastAPI. Система у меня должна будет быть закрытая, то есть никто не должен будет смотреть что там внутри.

Comment: если вы задачу запускаете в рамках обработки хттп запроса, должно быть вообще без разницы, есть там у пхп потоки или нет, ибо запрос отработал и завершился вместе с пхп. Ждать там чего то висеть ничего не будет, хоть в фоне его запустите. Много воды в вопросе. но нет конкретики, какую именно задачу вы решаете. Когда и как отправляете запрос, и когда и где вам надо получить ответ.

Comment: @teran решаю задачу получения сообщения от устройства по mqtt серверу. Запрос можно отправить в любое время. 
Клиент отправляет post запрос на сервер. В информации запроса находится задача. Сервер переносит задачу на mqtt сервер. После этого он должен получить ответ от устройства "принял". Когда ответ получен, сервер отправляет клиенту ответ "всё хорошо". 
Задача стоит получать этот ответ от устройства и отправлять его клиенту вовремя. Если с ответом "принял" вопросов нет, ибо он придет почти сразу же, то как отправлять клиенту сообщение от устройства вида "выполнил задачу" - не понятно.

Comment: проверять статус задачи по таймеру; использовать SSE; использовать сокеты.

Comment: @teran, в php для api врятли можно проверять статус задачи. Соответственно лучше написать дополнительный модуль, программу, которая будет следить за mqtt сервером и обновлять статус в базе данных?

Comment: условно когда создаете задачку себе, то пишите ее куда-то в базу и пихаете в очередь. Консьюмер у вас очередь разгребает и выполняет каким то образом полезную работу. В конце он должен отметить ее выполненной (в базе напрямую или обратная связь какая-то через очередь). На пхп вы ходите и условно раз в 5 сек проверяете этот статус (первичная реализация по таймеру будет проще, чем сокеты тащить).

Comment: @teran сокеты я и не хочу. Тогда буду записывать в базу данных, задаче будет присвое номер. Буду кидать задачу по номеру и кидать на сервер. Потом, когда устройство будет отвечать, то оно напишет на какую задачу присылает и ответ и по этому буду обновлять поле в базе данных. Вы говорите, что реализовать это на php в таймере. А как это сделать? Код же по своей сути работает только во время приема запросов.

Comment: таймер у вас в JS в клиенте дергает пхп и спрашивает, готова ли задача

Comment: @teran благодарю. Завтра попробую, отпишусь!